# Ruby-on-Rails + FriendlyId gem + Acts_as_Votable gem - getting a Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

In my index page I have the following as part of setting up the Acts_as_votable gem.

```
<%= link_to like_bike_path(bike), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" do %>
```

It was working fine until I added FriendlyId, probably because the like_bike_path is looking for an id not a friendlyID (ie vanity URL).  Is there a way to change

`like_bike_path`

to something like

```
like_friendly.find_path
```

Works on Localhost:3000 but Heroku logs tell me  `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method slug' for #<Bike"` for my two acts_as_votable calls "like_bike_path(bike)" and "<%= bike.get_upvotes.size %>".

thanks!

Comment: Hi, Dave! Could you please clarify what goes wrong? What's working not as you expected? Because acts_as_votable is more about model and I suppose that like_bike_path is just usual rails route.

Comment: Hi @kimrgrey!  Apologies for not clarifying the error.  Thanks for the follow up questions.  I think I solved the problem.  Still verifying.  The fix is to change @bike = Bike.friendly.find(bike_id) from what I had previously:  bike = Bike.find_by_id(bike_id) in the bike controller.   So I think the issue is just a rails route to your point.  The original error was a failed push to Heroku.

Comment: Great! I'm as one of the maintainers of the frienldy_id very glad to hear that our software is useful for you ;-) By the way, you can use module :finders to be able to call something like Bike.find(slug) instead of Bike.friendly.find(slug). It could solve some possible problems with cancancan and other libraries that expects resource to be searchable using simple find with id of resource.

Comment: Hi again @kimrgrey.  Seems to work on localhost:3000 but Heroku is choking.  Heroku logs tell me " ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `slug' for #<Bike" for my two acts_as_votable calls "like_bike_path(bike)" and "<%= bike.get_upvotes.size %>".  I'll try the :finders, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#app/models/bike.rb
class Bike < ActiveRecord::Base
   extend FriendlyId
   friendly_id :column, use: [:finders, :slugged]
end
```

This will allow use of the `slug` without having to change the default pattern in ActiveRecord... (`@bike = Bike.find params[:id]`).

--

In regards your `heroku` error, it means you have not got the database migrated (it doesn't include `slug` in its columns).

You need to make sure you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`, as well as ensuring that you've re-saved any `@bike` records (so the `slug` column is populated).

Comment: Thanks, @Rich!  I made sure I had :slug in params

`bike_params = params.require(:bike).permit(:name, :description, :image, :slug)`

and I did a `heroku run rake db:migrate`.  Fixed!